# Write correlated subquery in a WHERE Clause as join

Tags: sql

I have a query like below:

```
select 
  a.id, a.title, a.description
from
  my_table_name as a
where
  a.id in (select id from another_table b where b.id = 1)
```

My question is, is there any way I can avoid the subquery in where clause and use it in from clause itself without compromising of performance?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? In SQL Server the `IN`/`EXISTS` would be preferable than the inner join. Especially if the inner join brings back duplicates as `another_table` has multiple rows for an `a.id` that you then need to use `DISTINCT` to get rid of.

Comment: I have to code it for platform independent way, hence asked for plain sql query.

Comment: SQL is declarative. The `without compromising of performance` depends upon the specific RDBMS and its optimiser not the query syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. however I cannot optimize for specific RDBMS and must use one query for all, so probably using inner join as answered by theghostofc

Comment: And why I would like to avoid subquery in where clause is the framework I am using does not support correlated subquery in where clause yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `INNER JOIN` as:

```
select 
  a.id, a.title, a.description
from
  my_table_name as a INNER JOIN another_table as b ON (a.id = b.id and b.id = 1)
```

Or

```
select 
  a.id, a.title, a.description
from
  my_table_name as a INNER JOIN another_table as b ON a.id = b.id
where b.id = 1
```

> Both the queries may not return the same value for you. You may choose whatever works for you. Please use this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste code.

Comment: @Bohemian, can you explain the reason? I tried with my result set and produce same.

Comment: @Nagarjun Sure: if ids from table a appear multiple times in table b, the original query will show each matching row from table a only once, but the join will show the matching rows multiple times. See my answer for the fix.

Comment: Thank you. Fortunately, the both tables data is in one-to-one mapping, so there is no possibility of having cid (fkey to id in table a) repeated multiple times in table b. Though, your comment is valid for other situations.

Comment: The First query is not likely to perform faster. Putting the conditions in the `WHERE` or `INNER JOIN` makes no difference. (Also I just noticed the part about experimenting with `a.id = b.id` or `b.id = a.id `. Again this will make no difference.)

Comment: @MartinSmith, I have edited the post and have removed the statement about faster performing query. If you had down-voted the answer just for this reason, you may reconsider.

Comment: @Bohemian, I have seen such queries working fine even for one-to-many and many-to-many. Moreover, these are provided to the asker as choices which he may use at his own wish. I did not intend to discuss that the queries return same results or not. The asker may choose whichever applies (There is an OR :D). If that is the only reason for your down-vote (if you did) then you may like to reconsider.

Comment: I still find the part about experimenting with `a.id = b.id or b.id = a.id` problematic and IMO it should mention the caveat that `another_table(id)` must be unique.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I have removed that part too. Thanks for removing the down-vote

Answer (score 3):

Both of the answers given so far are incorrect in the general case (though the database may have unique constraints which ensure they are correct in a specific case)

If `another_table` might have multiple rows with the same `id` then the `INNER JOIN` will bring back duplicates that are not present in the `IN` version. Trying to remove them with `DISTINCT` can change the semantics if the columns from `my_table_name` themselves have duplicates.

A general rewrite would be

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.title,
       a.description
FROM   my_table_name AS a
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id
             FROM   another_table
             WHERE  id = 1) AS b
         ON b.id = a.id
```

The performance characteristics of this rewrite are implementation dependant.

Answer (score 2):

To express it as a join:

```
select distinct
  a.id, a.title, a.description
from my_table_name as a
join another_table b on b.id = a.id
where b.id = 1
```

The use of `distinct` is to produce the same results in case another_table has the same id more than once so the same row doesn't get returned multiple times.

Note: if combinations of id, name and description in my_table_name are not unique, this query won't return such duplicates as the original query would.

---

To guarantee to produce the same results, you need to ensure that the id's in another_table is unique. To do this as a join:

```
select
  a.id, a.title, a.description
from my_table_name as a
join (select distinct id from another_table) b on b.id = a.id
where b.id = 1
```

Comment: What if `a.id` was not unique to begin with? `DISTINCT` will give you a different result.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Are you suggesting that the combination of id, name and description is not unique?

Comment: @ta.speot.is funny, I never really thought about it, but I'm pretty sure the edit at the bottom is what's required to guarantee the same results as `where id in (...)`. I'm glad you posted your thoughts, because it got me thinking. Cheers

Comment: @ypercube lol. Dunno where that came from. Nevertheless, I'm glad you're here - I can't tember seeing a query like the one st the bottom, but I think it's the correct way to replace a `where id in (...)` as a join.